# Как найти элемент с двумя id

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть элемент

```
#landing#selected.card
```

Как мне его найти через `getElementById()`?

Comment: а как он в разметке выглядит? :-)

Comment: и не совсем понятно зачем два id. Ведь индефикатор позволяет нам выполнить точечный поиск.

Comment: Оставьте один из идентификаторов и воспользуйтесь `getElenemtById()`. Но как у вас появился такой элемент? Надо что-то где-то исправить.

Comment: @Danil Sizov  Очень просто! Добавьте третий идентификатор и по нему ищите элемент.:)

Comment: Просто мне нужно при нажатии удалять этот элемент из одного списка и добавлять в другой, #landing это идентификатор в объекте, который отвечает за свойства, а #selected это его состояние - выбранный или нет

Comment: И лосю, и ежику понятно, что состояние в id хранить неразумно

Comment: А как мне его нужно хранить, в какой то переменной?

Comment: определения идентификатора: Задает стилевой идентификатор — уникальное имя элемента, которое используется для изменения его стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты. Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз. Как у вас этот код браузеры вообще воспринимают? Покажите css этих id, уберём Ваши костыли с двумя id

Comment: хранить можно в дата атрибуте, или в классе например.

Comment: @sbaikov, ты говоришь про то, что нельзя использовать один и тот же id на разных элементах. В вопросе несколько id установлены у **одного** элемента

Comment: Весь css прописан в .card и я уже задал каждому блоку свой уникальный id, теперь ищу по нему.

Comment: ваша html разметка выглядит так? (div примера) - <div id="landing selected" class="card"></div>

Comment: А так разве можно? Только один ID на элемент и уникальный во всей области видимости.

Comment: @Other, на самом деле там интересно, спецификация по элементам вообще не запрещает несколько атрибутов id, плюс можно использовать всякие namespase для них, запрещает спецификация DOM Core, который говорит, что именно _id_ атрибут, должен быть один у элемента

Comment: @Grundy, в итоге - да, таки только один ID. Не суть важно кто запретил это.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#element').on('click', function() {
  $('#element').toggleClass('selected');
 })
  
  $('.targetList')
    .find('.selected')
    .appendTo('.someList);
```

Возможно стоит попробовать просто менять класс для выделеного элемента. Тогда можно будет автоматически добавлять во второй список элемент с этим классом.
Потом его можно и удалить.

Ну или как то так.

Answer (score 1):

У элемента всегда есть не более одного id. Сделать несколько невозможно. Если возникает необходимость в нескольких id, то следует вместо этого воспользоваться классами.

---

Сss-селектор с несколькими id `#a#b` формально валиден, но заведомо соответствует 0 элементов.

Если предположить, что кого-то всё же угораздило написать "несколько" id через пробел, то это всё равно один id (формально, некорректный, но все браузеры его съедят без проблем). В таком случае с ним можно работать следующим образом:

```js
document.getElementById("a b").textContent += "??"
```

```css
#a {
  color: red;
}

#b {
  color: green;
}

[id~="a"][id~="b"] {
  color: blue;
}

[id~="a"]:after {
  content: " - with word 'a' in id";
  font-style: italic;
}

#a\ b {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Just an A</div>
<div id="b">Just an B</div>
<div id="ab">AB is simple too</div>
<div id="a b">Really AB?</div>
<div id="b a">Really BA?</div>
```

> это если так id="a b", а не так id="a" id="b"

А так вообще не бывает - браузер использует только один из атрибутов:

```js
document.body.textContent = document.body.innerHTML
```

```html
<div id="a" id="b"></div>
```

В моём хроме выводится:

```html
<div id="a"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> document.body.textContent = document.body.innerHTML </script>
```

Comment: это если так `id="a b"`, а не так `id="a" id="b"`

Comment: @Grundy, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Ребята, давайте кодить по [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id). В спецификации указывается, что id - уникальный идентификатор, а значение атрибута - строка без пробелов. Соответственно, приведенный выше код невалидный.

Comment: @Mikl, уникальный на странице, а не у элемента

Comment: @Mikl, но браузерам пофиг на пробелы... А css валидный, кстати, кажется. Уникальность id в моём примере выполняется - это же не перечисление, а просто строка.